# Operations on Booster (XGBoost)

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, data-science, xgboost

I need some help to do a bagging aggregation of different XGBoost models (with types Booster). The idea is after to store one model, the final one, into a pickle file.

I start by creating a dummy dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import pickle

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
dummy_df['D'] = -15 * dummy_df['A'] + 32 * dummy_df['B']
X = dummy_df.drop('D', axis=1)
y = dummy_df['D']
```

I establish some parameters I'd like to test (resulting for instance from a gridsearch):

```
params = {'eta': 0.06,  # learning rate
          'tree_method': "auto",#considering my dummy df, might be more interesting to use "gblinear" of course...
          'max_depth': 3,
          'subsample': 0.75,
          'colsample_bytree': 0.75,
          'colsample_bylevel': 0.75,
          'min_child_weight': 5,
          'alpha': 10,
          'objective': 'reg:linear',
          'eval_metric': 'rmse',
          'random_state': 99,
          'silent': True}
```

Finally, I create my cross-validation scheme:

```
accu = 0
n_splits = 5
folds = KFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True, random_state=1)

for n_fold, (train_idx, valid_idx) in enumerate(folds.split(X, y)):
    train_x, train_y = X.iloc[train_idx], y.iloc[train_idx]
    valid_x, valid_y = X.iloc[valid_idx], y.iloc[valid_idx]


    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_x, train_y)
    dvalid = xgb.DMatrix(valid_x, valid_y)
    watchlist = [(dtrain, 'train'), (dvalid, 'valid')]
    model = xgb.train(params, dtrain, 2500, watchlist, maximize=False, early_stopping_rounds=40, verbose_eval=50)

    if accu == 0:
        model_to_save = model
        accu += 1
    else:
        model_to_save += model
```

It trains properly for the first and second iterations in my for loop, but when needs to add the 2 first iterations (final line), I get the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Booster' and 'Booster'

Is there any way in Python to add 2 Boosters? And also to divide a Booster by an integer since I'll have to divide at the end `model_to_save` by `n_splits`?

PS: Storing all the XGBoost models is not an option considering other constraints I can face later on.

Comment: What do you expect a sum of two Booster objects to be? At the moment it does not make sense to me.

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi I expect to average the different XGBoost models created and validated on different sets. This helps reducing the variance and the overfitting as well. After having done this, I'll store the average model into a pickle that I'll use to predict the output of data created in the future.

Comment: Different models have different tree structure (splits on different features). So it does not make sense to average models- only their predictions. What you describe is indeed useful, but is impossible at model level. Thus, you are doomed to pickle several individual models if you want to reduce variance by averaging

Comment: Indeed they have different tree structure, but so have the trees in the random forest algorithm, algorithm which aggregates these different trees. What I am looking for is to aggregate as well my different XGB models.
Now of course I can store each model, and average their results, but I am still hoping my initial idea is not doomed.

Comment: One can not compare aggregation of RF and GBM. It is easy to merge RF models, as all trees are grown **independently** and merging two independent models with N1 and N2 trees is equivalent to a model with N1+N2 trees (assuming the same input feature set). In GBM each tree depends on previous trees, thus they are not independent and can not be merged with the same philosophy.

Comment: I guess there is a misunderstanding, I might not have explained myself clearly. The comparison on RF and XGB stands on the following idea here: all trees in RF are grown independently but with a different training set (different samples of data and of features). And then all those trees are aggregated. Here my 5 XGB models are also trained independently on different training sets. And my goal is to aggregate the 5 models the same way RF does with its different trees. Indeed, _In GBM each tree depends on previous trees_, but my goal is not to isolate each tree. Hope it's clearer...

Comment: Ok, let's work out the confusion. I think, I might be still confused here: *"And then all those trees are aggregated"*. RF **trees** are not aggregated (they are all kept separately). **Predictions** of the RF trees are aggregated. The caveat is that one can stack more RF trees together and the aggregation rule on their prediction remains the same. But one can not stack together multiple GBDT's are use the nominal GBM aggregation rule on their predictions.

Comment: I see. I thought that Python aggregated RF trees, while in fact they are all kept as such and the individual predictions are aggregated. I'll reproduce the same scheme with my XGB models. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

params = {'eta': 0.06,  # learning rate
'tree_method': "auto",#considering my dummy df, might be more interesting to use "gblinear" of course...
'max_depth': 3,
'subsample': 0.75,
'colsample_bytree': 0.75,
'colsample_bylevel': 0.75,
'min_child_weight': 5,
'alpha': 10,
'objective': 'reg:linear',
'eval_metric': 'rmse',
'random_state': 99,
'silent': True}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).